# Using the name of a data frame column as a parameter value for a function which filters that column in the data frame

Tags: r, function, filter, dplyr, names

I would like to write a function which uses `dplyr::filter()` within the function. When writing the function I ran into an issue with using a parameter name in the function that is also a name of one of the columns of the data frame I am filtering.

Suppose I call the data frame to be filtered `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(
a = c(1:10),
b = c(2,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,4,4)
)
```

and name the function `test.filter()`,

```
test.filter <- function(b, test.data = dat){
dat.t <- filter(test.data,
              b == b)
return(dat.t)
}
```

Here I am passing a *value* `b` to the function and asking it to filter the *column* `b` based on the value `b`. I believe the function

```
test.filter(b = 4,
        test.data = dat)
```

should produce the same result as

```
filter(dat,
   b == 4)
```

However this is not the case. I am wondering if there is something I am not considering in terms of the scope of a function. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is a case where the argument 'b' of the function is the same as the column name.  One option is to do `!!` inside the function argument

```
test.filter <- function(b, test.data = dat){
   filter(test.data,
           b == !!b)

   }

test.filter(b = 4,
     test.data = dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the argument passed to the function is similar to one of the column name in the dataframe, we can use the curly-curly (`{{ }}`) operator from `rlang` to evaluate column name

```
library(rlang)

test.filter <- function(b, test.data = dat) {
      dplyr::filter(dat,{{b}} == b)
}

test.filter(b = 4,test.data = dat)
#   a b
#1  9 4
#2 10 4


test.filter(b = 2,test.data = dat)
#  a b
#1 1 2
#2 2 2
#3 3 2
#4 4 2
#5 5 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful answers. A friend let me know that the underlying reason for the issue is dplyr uses lazy eval, so `b==b` evaluates to all true.